# Why is lateral epicondylitis 5 times more common than medial epicondylitis?

Tags: epicondylitis, tendons

http://www.mdguidelines.com/epicondylitis-medial-and-lateral says:

> Incidence and Prevalence: Lateral epicondylitis is at least 5 times more common than medial epicondylitis (Mercier). The exact incidence of lateral epicondylitis is difficult to determine, although among the US population it is estimated at 1% to 3% annually (Bryant; Verhaar). Medial epicondylitis accounts for only about 10% to 20% of all epicondylitis (Young). Approximately 15% of patients experience bilateral symptoms.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golfer%27s_elbow :

> Epicondylitis is much more common on the lateral side of the elbow (tennis elbow), rather than the medial side
>   Why is lateral epicondylitis 5 times more common than medial epicondylitis?

*Otoshi, Kenichi, Misa Takegami, Miho Sekiguchi, Yoshihiro Onishi, Shin Yamazaki, Koji Otani, Hiroaki Shishido, Shunichi Fukuhara, Shinichi Kikuchi, and Shinichi Konno. "[Chronic hyperglycemia increases the risk of lateral epicondylitis: the Locomotive Syndrome and Health Outcome in Aizu Cohort Study (LOHAS).](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=11069717801761190432&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22)" SpringerPlus 4, no. 1 (2015): 1-9.*

> In this study, the overall prevalence of lateral and medial epicondylitis was 2.5 % and 0.3 %, respectively, which are comparable with previous epidemiologic studies conducted in the general population.

[image]

I wonder whether it is due to human activities or some intrinsic differences between lateral and medial epicondyles.